# Update or Ignore || Update or Replace

Tags: sqlite

I saw alot of examples on Insert or Replace or Insert or Ignore on sqlite3 database. But I won't want to insert a new record when I only want to update and replace the same values found in the database. Or ignore the duplicated record found in the database and update rest of the values.

Sample Database

```
ID       Name        Number      Address    
1        John        81234999    Sans
```

In this case, if let's say I update only the number and the address remains the same. It should either update and replace with the same value. Or vice versa for updating address but not number. And lastly, updating number and address together.
Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

You can update a single column without impacting the others. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: no I'm looking if i can do update or replace any values that are duplicated.

Comment: Unless a column has a uniqueness constraint you would not be restricted from updating or inserting any value you want.